# Loop de envio de emails com PHP

Tags: php, while, mailer

Pessoal esse é o meu primeiro post e gostaria muito da ajuda de vocês: Tenho uma consulta num banco de dados que envia email automático através do PHP Mailer caso a atividade esteja em atraso, até aí tudo bem, o problema tá na repetição, caso tenha 3 emails para enviar é enviado para o primeiro ok, depois o segundo recebe ok (mas o primeiro email tb recebe dados do segundo que não era pra receber) e por fim o primeiro email recebe os dados da terceira atividade (que não era pra receber). Alguém poderia me dar uma luz? Segue o código:

```
require 'conexao.php';

date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
$hoje = date('Y-m-d H:i');

$conexao = conexao::getInstance();
$sql = 'SELECT ASSUNTO, PRAZO, RESPONSAVEL_GERAL, EMAIL_RESPONSAVEL FROM agenda WHERE PRAZO < :data';
$stm = $conexao->prepare($sql);
$stm->bindValue(':data', $hoje);
$stm->execute();
$clientes = $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    require_once("class/class.phpmailer.php");

    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);

    $mail->IsSMTP();




try {
     $mail->Host = 'smtp.meuhost.com.br'; 
     $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;  
     $mail->Port       = 587; 
     $mail->Username = 'contato@meudoinio.com.br';
     $mail->Password = 'minha_senha';

     $mail->SetFrom('contato@meudominio.com.br', 'Agenda OnLine'); 
     $mail->Subject = 'Lembrete de Atividades em Atraso';


        foreach($clientes as $cliente):

       // Aqui pego o email do BD
        $mail->AddAddress($cliente->EMAIL_RESPONSAVEL;, 'Teste de Atividades em Atraso');
         // E aqui pego o assunto
             $mail->MsgHTML($cliente->ASSUNTO); 

             $mail->Send();
             echo "Mensagem enviada com sucesso para '.$cliente->EMAIL_RESPONSAVEL'.</p>\n";

             $email = '';

        sleep(10);

        endforeach;


    }catch (phpmailerException $e) {
      echo $e->errorMessage();
}


?>
```

Comment: Tem um erro de sintaxe aqui: `$cliente->EMAIL_RESPONSAVEL;,`

Comment: Acho eu que aqui vc esta adicionando todos emails do foreach cliente para receber a msg.

´// Aqui pego o email do BD
        $mail->AddAddress($cliente->EMAIL_RESPONSAVEL;, 'Teste de Atividades em Atraso');´

Voce precisa limpar os endereços antigos ou criar um novo email.

Comment: Fiz assim pra deixar menos poluído e saber se foi enviado:


  foreach($clientes as $cliente):
  
  $email = $cliente->EMAIL_RESPONSAVEL;
   
  
    $mail->AddAddress($email, 'Teste de Atividades em Atraso');
  
    $mail->MsgHTML($cliente->ASSUNTO); 
  
    $mail->Send();
    echo "Mensagem enviada com sucesso para '.$cliente->ASSUNTO'.</p>\n";
    echo "Mensagem enviada com sucesso para '.$cliente->EMAIL_RESPONSAVEL'.</p>\n";
    
  sleep(10);

  endforeach;
 
Interessante que no browser mostra como se tivesse enviado para cada email independente sem problemas.

Comment: Chame `$mail->clearAddresses()` depois do envio

Comment: bfavaretto Funcionou, parei de receber 3 vezes (ou mais) no primeiro email, porém só recebo os dois primeiros, por exemplo: A atividade 1 vai pro gmail, as atividades 2 e 3 vão para o hotmail, porém no hotmail só chega a atividade 2.... a atividade 3 se perde no meio do caminho. O que pode ser?

Comment: Pessoal agradeço a ajuda de todos. A dica do bfavaretto funcionou perfeitamente. Coloquei $mail->clearAddresses() depois do envio e funcionou. Obrigado!

Comment: Se você quer enviar mensagens para vários destinatários de forma exclusiva, usando uma mesma instância do objeto PHPMailer, no seu loop,  antes de chamar AddAddress(), você deve chamar o método ClearAddresses().